# Reusable and testable JavaScript code for URL fragment-based tab navigation logic

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, functional-programming

### Foreword

As a personal project, I've been creating a SPA blog (available [here](https://aster89.github.io/#posts)), which features 4 tabs ([Thoughts](https://aster89.github.io/#bitten-by-sso), [Projects](https://aster89.github.io/#projects), [Readings](https://aster89.github.io/#suggested-books), and [CV](https://aster89.github.io/#about-me)), each accessible via one of four radio buttons, and several entries per tab. When one of the tabs is selected, an associated fragment is appended to URL, and one can enter that URL+fragment in the address bar to go directly to that tab; similarly one can enter a fragment pointing to one of the items, and the page will open on whichever tab that item belongs to, and scroll to that element (e.g. [this link](https://aster89.github.io/#winzoz) sends you to the last entry in the second tab).

The logic is implemented in JavaScript (I helped myself with jQuery, but that is probably incidental), and relies on the following

- a callback for when one of the radio buttons is clicked (to allow navigation via those buttons) that has the effect of changing the fragment of the URL;
- a callback on the `'hashchange'`, to react to the click of one of the radio buttons, and to allow one to go to one tab/element by entering the appropriate URL.

The code I wrote initially was [like this](https://github.com/Aster89/aster89.github.io/blob/ebbbd05aed5e01eef1ec7cf635dc062bea93fd75/js/tabs.js)
(I'm not asking for a review of the logic I chose, as I'll probably ask an ad-hoc question in the future, nor of the following code, but a review of how I change it.):

```javascript
$(document).ready(() => {

  const isTab = id => $('#' + id).filter('.tab-page').length != 0;

  const decodeHash = hash => {

    let selectedTab, selectedElem;

    const maybeTabId = hash + '-tab';

    if (isTab(maybeTabId)) {
      selectedTab = hash;
    } else {
      selectedElem = hash;
      selectedTab = _.join('', _.dropLast(4, $('#' + selectedElem).parents('.tab-page').attr('id')));
      if (!selectedTab || selectedTab.length == 0) {
        location.hash = '';
        return;
      }
    }
    return [selectedTab, selectedElem];

  }

  $(window).on('hashchange', () => {

    const [selectedTab, selectedElem] = decodeHash(location.hash.substr(1));

    if ($('.tab-page:visible').length != 1 || selectedTab + '-tab' != $('.tab-page:visible').attr('id')) {
      $('.tab-page:visible').hide();
      $('.tab-page' + '#' + selectedTab + '-tab').show();
      $('nav input[value=' + selectedTab + ']').prop('checked', true);
    }
    if (selectedElem) {
      const elem = $('#' + selectedElem)[0];
      if (elem) {
        elem.scrollIntoView(); // TODO: must scroll a bit down to avoid being covered by the top bar
      } else {
        location.hash = '#' + selectedTab;
      }
    }
  });

  $('nav > .site-nav input').click((event) => {
    location.hash = $(event.currentTarget).val().toString();
  });

  if (location.hash.length == 0) {
    location.hash = $('nav input[checked]').val().toString();
  }

  $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

I haven't written any tests yet, but I relalized I couldn't test anything of this code, not even if I wanted to, because the code above is a feast of global variables: there's the one, big HTML file, plus all the CSS files, which represent all together a big global variable that I easily access and edit via JavaScript/jQuery, making it impossible to track what's going on if something goes wrong. (And iIrc, this code had some bug already, which I discovered while updating it as written in the following.)

### The code to be reviewed

So I decided to embrace a more functional programming approach, and factor out every piece of code that has side effects/relies on global state (essentially any read or write operations on the HTML/CSS), and inject them in the logic via lambdas.

Step by step I came up with [the following](https://github.com/Aster89/aster89.github.io/blob/0660d7b57fb03dc092090eefee6597cb36b5aae8/js/tabs.js), where the `setupTabs` function implements the same logic as the previous piece of code, except that it is parametriezed with respect to every single side-effecty function:

```javascript
const isString = s => typeof s === 'string' || s instanceof String;
const dropDashTab = str => isString(str) ? str.replace(/-tab$/, '') : undefined;
const makeDecodeHash = (isTab, getParentTab) =>
  str => {

    let selectedElem;
    let selectedTab;

    const maybeTabId = str + '-tab';

    if (isTab(maybeTabId)) {
      selectedTab = str;
    } else {
      selectedElem = str;
      if (!selectedElem || selectedElem.length == 0) {
        return undefined;
      }
      selectedTab = getParentTab(selectedElem);
      if (!selectedTab || selectedTab.length == 0) {
        return undefined;
      }
    }
    return [selectedTab, selectedElem];
  };

function setupTabs({
  actionOnElem,
  check,
  getDefaultHash,
  getElemById,
  getHash,
  getId,
  getParentTab,
  getTabInput,
  getTabPage,
  getVisibleTabs,
  hide,
  isTab,
  setClickCallback,
  setHash,
  setHashChangeCallback,
  show,
  tabInputCallback
}) {

  setHashChangeCallback(() => {

    const decodeHash = makeDecodeHash(isTab, getParentTab);

    const maybeHash = decodeHash(getHash().substr(1));

    if (!maybeHash) {
      const visibleTabs = getVisibleTabs();
      const n = visibleTabs.length;
      console.assert(n == 1, "Unexpectedly, " + n + " instead of 1 tab is visible.");
      setHash(dropDashTab(getId(visibleTabs)));
      return;
    }

    const [selectedTab, selectedElem] = maybeHash;

    const visibleTabs = getVisibleTabs();
    let n = visibleTabs.length;
    console.assert(n <= 1, "Unexpectedly, " + n + " visible tabs; it should be 0 or 1 tab.");

    if (visibleTabs.length == 0 || selectedTab + '-tab' != getId(visibleTabs)) {
      hide(visibleTabs);
      show(getTabPage(selectedTab));
      check(getTabInput(selectedTab));
    }

    n = getVisibleTabs().length;
    console.assert(n == 1, "Unexpectedly, " + n + " instead of 1 tab is visible.");

    if (selectedElem) {
      const elem = getElemById(selectedElem);
      if (elem) {
        actionOnElem(elem);
      } else {
        setHash(selectedTab);
      }
    }
  });

  setClickCallback(tabInputCallback);

  if (getHash().length == 0) {
    setHash(getDefaultHash());
  }
};
```

The calling code, then, simply specifies all the inputs, [like this](https://github.com/Aster89/aster89.github.io/blob/0660d7b57fb03dc092090eefee6597cb36b5aae8/js/main.js):

```javascript
$(document).ready(() => {
  setupTabs({
    // Actions (impure functions, as they read from/write to the global state
    // represented by the HTML):
    //  - read
    getDefaultHash: () => $('nav input[checked]').val().toString(),
    getElemById: id => document.getElementById(id),
    getHash: () => location.hash,
    getId: e => e.attr('id'),
    getParentTab: elem => dropDashTab($('#' + elem).parents('.tab-page').attr('id')),
    getTabPage: name => $('.tab-page' + '#' + name + '-tab'),
    getTabInput: name => $('nav input[value=' + name + ']'),
    getVisibleTabs: () => $('.tab-page:visible'),
    isTab: str => $('#' + str).filter('.tab-page').length != 0,
    //  - write
    actionOnElem: e => { e.scrollIntoView(); }, // TODO: must scroll a bit down to avoid being covered by the top bar
    check: cb => { cb.prop('checked', true); },
    hide: e => { e.hide(); },
    show: e => { e.show(); },
    setClickCallback: f => { $('nav input').click(f); },
    setHash: h => { location.hash = h; },
    setHashChangeCallback: f => { $(window).on('hashchange', f); },
    tabInputCallback: eventObj => { location.hash = $(eventObj.currentTarget).val().toString(); }
  });
  $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

I felt the above was indeed an improvement, because I could

- find a few bugs (I can't remember any more and can't bother looking for it),
- exercise this code in a totally different environment by simply changing all the inputs to `setupTabs`; for instance, below (as well as [here](https://aster89.github.io/docs/section-navigation.html#kssref-navigation-tabs)) is a snippet that tests the code, without interacting with the fragment of the URL, but with an element in the snippet itself; you can try writing `tab1`/`tab2`/`tab3`/`elem11`/`elem12`/… in the edit box.

When you run the snippet below, you have to scroll to see all of it.

```js
const isString = s => typeof s === 'string' || s instanceof String;
const dropDashTab = str => isString(str) ? str.replace(/-tab$/, '') : undefined;
const makeDecodeHash = (isTab, getParentTab) =>
  str => {

    let selectedElem;
    let selectedTab;

    const maybeTabId = str + '-tab';

    if (isTab(maybeTabId)) {
      selectedTab = str;
    } else {
      selectedElem = str;
      if (!selectedElem || selectedElem.length == 0) {
        return undefined;
      }
      selectedTab = getParentTab(selectedElem);
      if (!selectedTab || selectedTab.length == 0) {
        return undefined;
      }
    }
    return [selectedTab, selectedElem];
  };

function setupTabs({
  actionOnElem,
  check,
  getDefaultHash,
  getElemById,
  getHash,
  getId,
  getParentTab,
  getTabInput,
  getTabPage,
  getVisibleTabs,
  hide,
  isTab,
  setClickCallback,
  setHash,
  setHashChangeCallback,
  show,
  tabInputCallback
}) {

  setHashChangeCallback(() => {

    const decodeHash = makeDecodeHash(isTab, getParentTab);

    const maybeHash = decodeHash(getHash().substr(1));

    if (!maybeHash) {
      const visibleTabs = getVisibleTabs();
      const n = visibleTabs.length;
      console.assert(n == 1, "Unexpectedly, " + n + " instead of 1 tab is visible.");
      setHash(dropDashTab(getId(visibleTabs)));
      return;
    }

    const [selectedTab, selectedElem] = maybeHash;

    const visibleTabs = getVisibleTabs();
    let n = visibleTabs.length;
    console.assert(n <= 1, "Unexpectedly, " + n + " visible tabs; it should be 0 or 1 tab.");

    if (visibleTabs.length == 0 || selectedTab + '-tab' != getId(visibleTabs)) {
      hide(visibleTabs);
      show(getTabPage(selectedTab));
      check(getTabInput(selectedTab));
    }

    n = getVisibleTabs().length;
    console.assert(n == 1, "Unexpectedly, " + n + " instead of 1 tab is visible.");

    if (selectedElem) {
      const elem = getElemById(selectedElem);
      if (elem) {
        actionOnElem(elem);
      } else {
        setHash(selectedTab);
      }
    }
  });

  setClickCallback(tabInputCallback);

  if (getHash().length == 0) {
    setHash(getDefaultHash());
  }
};


(function() {
  // Load the script
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js';
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.addEventListener('load', () => {

    $(document).ready(() => {
      // some helper function
      const prependHash = str => str == '' ? str : '#' + str;
      // in this demo shown/hidden are actually mapped to green-and-boxed/red-not-boxed
      $('.tab-page').css('display', 'initial');
      $('.tab-page').css('color', 'red');
      $('.tab-page li').css('display', 'table')
      setupTabs({
        //  - read
        getDefaultHash: () => $('nav input[checked]').val().toString(),
        getElemById: id => $('#' + id),
        getHash: () => prependHash($('#hash').val().toString()),
        getId: e => e.attr('id'),
        getParentTab: elem => dropDashTab($('#' + elem).parents('.tab-page').attr('id')),
        getTabPage: name => $('.tab-page' + '#' + name + '-tab'),
        getTabInput: name => $('nav input[value=' + name + ']'),
        getVisibleTabs: () => $('.tab-page').filter(
          function( index ) {
            return this.style.color === 'green';
          }
        ),
        isTab: str => $('#' + str).filter('.tab-page').length != 0,
        //  - write
        actionOnElem: e => {
          $('.tab-page li').css('font-weight', 'normal');
          $('.tab-page li').css('background-color', 'transparent');
          e.css('font-weight', 'bold');
          e.css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
        },
        check: cb => { cb.prop('checked', true); },
        hide: e => {
          $('.tab-page li').css('font-weight', 'normal');
          $('.tab-page li').css('background-color', 'transparent');
          e.css('color', 'red');
          e.children().first().css('border-style', 'none');
        },
        show: e => {
          $('.tab-page li').css('font-weight', 'normal');
          $('.tab-page li').css('background-color', 'transparent');
          e.css('color', 'green');
          e.children().first().css('border-style', 'solid');
        },
        setClickCallback: f => { $('nav input').click(f); },
        setHash: h => { $('#hash').val(h); },
        setHashChangeCallback: f => { $('#hash').change(f); },
        tabInputCallback: eventObj => {
          $('#hash').val($(eventObj.currentTarget).val().toString()).change();
        }
      });
      $('#hash').change();
    });
  });
  document.head.appendChild(script);
})();
```

```css
.tab-page {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="name">URL:</label>
<input type="text"
       value="sch://some/url/#"
       minlength="0" maxlength="8" size="10"
       readonly>
<input type="text"
       id="hash"
       name="name"
       placeholder="hash (without the leading #)">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="nav-tabs" id="tab1-radio" value="tab1">
      <label for="tab1-radio">show only tab 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="nav-tabs" id="tab2-radio" value="tab2" checked>
      <label for="tab2-radio">show only tab 2 (this is the default)</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="nav-tabs" id="tab3-radio" value="tab3">
      <label for="tab3-radio">show only tab 3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div>
  <div class="tab-page" id="tab1-tab">
    tab1
    <ul>
      <li id="elem11">elem11</li>
      <li id="elem12">elem12</li>
      <li id="elem13">elem13</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-page" id="tab2-tab">
    tab2
    <ul>
      <li id="elem21">elem21</li>
      <li id="elem22">elem22</li>
      <li id="elem23">elem23</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-page" id="tab3-tab">
    tab3
    <ul>
      <li id="elem31">elem31</li>
      <li id="elem32">elem32</li>
      <li id="elem33">elem33</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```